# SQL Server stored procedure that inserts if not exist and returns a specific property (column value)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value, power-automate

I have a stored procedure that inserts a record if it doesn't exist, but I would like to adapt this a little. I would like the stored procedure to return a column's value.

So far I have this:

```
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM tableName
                  WHERE DATALENGTH(ColumnValueToReturn) = 0
                    AND property = @property ...)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tableName (...)
       VALUES (...)
   END
END
```

I am confused and unsure on what the best option would be here, there are 3 scenarios:

1. There is an existing record + `ColumnValueToReturn` is not empty
2. There is an existing record + `ColumnValueToReturn` is NULL/Empty
3. There is no existing record

I would like that in case 1, the stored procedure returns the `ColumnValueToReturn` value, and in cases 2 & 3 it returns a custom value (0 or any string).

Can anyone suggest ways to do this?

Mind that this is used in a Microsoft Flow (https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) so there are some limitations sometimes.

Thank you all for any help or suggestions !

Kind regards

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server? (If you are, add <sql-server> tag to your question.)

Comment: Do you know if you are performing an update or insert prior to calling the stored procedure?

Comment: @jarlh, done, sorry for not specifying that. **Ross Bush**, no i don't and that is why i am checking  IF NOT EXISTS ... in the SP.

Comment: Use if/else logic as below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if exists (SELECT 1 FROM tableName
                  WHERE datalength(**ColumnValueToReturn**)=0
                  AND property = @property ...)

select ColumnValueToReturn FROM tableName WHERE datalength(**ColumnValueToReturn**)=0
                  AND property = @property ...
else  
begin     
 INSERT INTO tableName (...)
 VALUES (...)
 select defaultvalue
end
```

Comment: Daniel, just saw your upate :) i think this might be it, ill try this tomorrow and let you know how that went !

Comment: Daniel, i would like to understand it completely before implementing it, Why is the select ColumnValueToReturn statement necessary after the IF statement since we are selecting it in the IF if it exists ? Thank you for explaining !

Comment: Basically what that’s saying is that if it exists we will select it - the 2nd select is what is actually returning the data

Comment: Daniel, i do understand that, what i don't understand is why the 2nd select statement is needed after the IF (before the ELSE), so if it exists 'select 1 ...' , why still 'select ColumnValueToReturn  ...'  after that if we already are selecting it by stating 'select 1 ...' ? Sorry if i am unclear about the question :)

Comment: The first select is not returning the data - it is just checking to see if it exists - the second select returns the data

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your time and solution, it works. I am gonna run more tests to see if the current logic is good or not but your solution works ! Kind regards !

Comment: OK great to hear.  Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Everything is totally clear, thank you again. Got everything working as expected ;) Have a great weekend, Kind regards